# UITableView - CanPerfromAction delegate method

Tags: updates, uimenucontroller, uitableview

When an `UITableViewCell` is created inside an `UITableView`, its available actions are retrieve from the `UITableViewDelegate` automatically by:

```
– tableView:canPerformAction:forRowAtIndexPath:withSender:
```

Supposing that after some elapsed time, that initial created UITableViewCell still being visible on the screen but had its internal custom status updated and now it is able to handle more actions than before. The actions associated to that cell never get updated until the UITableView re-dequeue a new cell.

This schema may help to clarify my question:

- myCell = new cell with `copy:` action available.
- tableview get available actions for `myCell`.
- user keep pressing the cell and a `UIMenuController` is being displayed with the `Copy` action.
- myCell get its internal status updated and can now handle both `copy:` and `delete:` actions.
- user keep pressing the cell again and the `UIMenuController` still being displayed only with the `Copy` option.

Inside my `canPerformAction:...` I am returning different values depending on current cell internal status.

Note: If I just perform a small scroll which makes myCell to be re-dequeued, when pressing the cell again, the `UIMenuController` will display the updated `copy:` and `delete:` actions.

So the question is, how can I make my UITableView to ask for new available actions for updated cells?